# Sistemas de ecuaciones diferenciales en Python

Tags: python, numpy

tengo problemas para resolver el siguiente sistema de ecuaciones:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R1=8
R2=3
L1=1 
L2=1 

def RLC(I,t):
  di1_t=(-(R1+R2)/L2)*I[0] + (R2/L2)*I[1] + (100*np.sin(t))/L2 + di2_t

  di2_t=(R2/L1)*I[0] - (R2/L1)*I[1]  

  return di1_t,di2_t


i0 = 0,0

t = np.linspace(0,2,100)

sol=odeint(RLC, i0, t)
```

Debido a que las ecuaciones son co-dependientes, cual seria una posible solucion para el mismo??

Comment: ¿Cual es la ecuacion que requieres resolver?

Comment: ¿Te funcionó mi solución?

Comment: Cuál es la interpretación física de tus ecuaciones?

Answer (score 1):

No tienes que añadir nada más, el problema es que no has separado las ecuaciones correctamente, por ejemplo una solucion seria reemplazar `di2_t` en `di1_t`:

```
def RLC(I,t): 
    di1_t=(-(R1+R2)/L2)*I[0] + (R2/L2)*I[1] + (100*np.sin(t))/L2 + (R2/L1)*I[0] - (R2/L1)*I[1]
    di2_t=(R2/L1)*I[0] - (R2/L1)*I[1] 
    return di1_t, di2_t
```

O sencillamente cambiar el orden de las instrucciones:

```
def RLC(I,t):
    di2_t=(R2/L1)*I[0] - (R2/L1)*I[1]  
    di1_t=(-(R1+R2)/L2)*I[0] + (R2/L2)*I[1] + (100*np.sin(t))/L2 + di2_t
    return di1_t, di2_t
```

Ademas para hacer más legible tu código puedes desempaquetar la tupla usando `i1, i2 = I` y reemplazando `I[0]` e `I[1]` por `i1` e`i2`, respectivamente. Ejecutando el siguiente codigo obtenemos:

```
R1=8
R2=3
L1=1 
L2=1 

def RLC(I,t):
    i1, i2 = I
    di2_t=(R2/L1)*i1 - (R2/L1)*i2  
    di1_t=(-(R1+R2)/L2)*i1 + (R2/L2)*i2 + (100*np.sin(t))/L2 + di2_t
    return di1_t, di2_t

i0 = 0,0

t = np.linspace(0,2,100)

sol=odeint(RLC, i0, t)
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], label="i1_t")
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1], label="i2_t")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]